# I ran into memory problems using this function

Tags: c#

I want to change the "$" characters in P to S in a way for example if S is "e" and P is "$agl$" the first input would be eagle and the second is eagleagleagle and so on.

This little function solves this until my N(the times I want to repeat this method) is a bit bigger. That's when I run into memory problems. I would gladly take any suggestions on how to make it work.

```cs
using System;

namespace SZTF1HF_new {
  class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
      string S = Console.ReadLine();
      string P = Console.ReadLine();
      int N = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
      int MIN = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
      int MAX = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

      string Funct(string S, string P) {
        string temp = P.Replace("$", S);
        N--;
        if (N > 0) {
          return Funct(temp, P);
        }
        return temp;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Couldn't you do ReplaceAll? Is there a specific reason you're going with a recursive approach. School assignment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `while` loop which loops through a block of code as long as a specified condition is true over recursion.

The concept of Recursion and Iteration is to execute a set of instructions repeatedly and the difference between them is that recursion is simply a method call in which the method being called is the same as the one making the call while iteration is when a loop is repeatedly executed until a certain condition is met. one of the key difference between then is that recursion can cause infinite recursion which can lead to system crash whereas, infinite iteration consumes CPU cycles. Recursion also repeatedly invokes the mechanism, and consequently the overhead, of method calls and this can be quite expensive in both processor time and memory space while iteration doesn’t.

```
string Funct(string S, string P) {
    while(N > 0){
        P = P.Replace("$", S);
        N--;
     }

    return P;
}
```

Comment: or `for(; N > 0, N--) {...}`

Comment: I highly appreciate your answer, and it's always great to learn something, but I don't think my problem can be solved using while. The output with while will always be "eagle", and my goal isn't to create a string chain. I want to - in a way - insert into the string. Here are some examples for what I mean:
Input:
oe
$nik
10
Output: oeniknikniknikniknikniknikniknik
Input:
e
$agl$
2
Output: eagleagleagle